# Draftsight 2017 SP2 Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, cad

I just installed Draftsight 2017 SP2 on my Ubuntu 17.04. Everything went fine, even the registration. After I registered my email and reopen Draftsight I can't Accept the License Agreement. Everything I try to do in the program crashes it.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x2ada800
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x2ada800
(DraftSight:14036): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
(DraftSight:14036): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(DraftSight:14036): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

I have installed the same Draftsight version on Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest Mesa drivers and everything works fine. Even the License Agreement.

Any help?